# Is there a more concise way to conditionally loop over rows in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a simple dataframe and would like to apply a function to a particular column based on the status of another column.

```
myDF = pd.DataFrame({'trial': ['A','B','A','B','A','B'], 'score': [1,2,3,4,5,6]})
```

I would like to multiply each observation in the score column by 10, but only if the trial name is 'A'. If it is 'B', I would like the score to remain the same.

I have a working version that does what I need, but I'm wondering if there is a way I can do this without having to create the new dataframe. Not that it makes a huge difference, but eight lines of code seems pretty long and I'm guessing there might be a simpler solution I have overlooked.

```
newDF = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['trial','score'])
for row in myDF.iterrows():    
    if row[1][0] == 'A':
        newScore = {'trial': 'A', 'score': row[1][1]*10}
        newDF = newDF.append(newScore, ignore_index=True)
    else:
        newScore = {'trial': 'B', 'score': row[1][1]}
        newDF = newDF.append(newScore, ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Kindly post your expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas is pretty fast, and does the job well! But, functions like `.iterrows()` is dead slow compared to other methods. There are various articles on this topic, [one such](https://towardsdatascience.com/different-ways-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-pandas-dataframe-performance-comparison-dc0d5dcef8fe) is linked here.

Now, you can simply use `.apply()` function. Which will work wonders - and you can even fit any custom functions!

Here is an example of your work:

```py
myDF["score"] = myDF.apply(lambda x : x[1] * 10 if x[0] == "A" else x[1], axis = 1)
```

You can even apply any functions using `.apply` and `lambda` as below:

```py
def updateScore(trial, score):
    return score if trial != 'A' else score * 10

myDF["score"] = myDF.apply(lambda x : updateScore(trial = x[0], score = x[1]), axis = 1)
```

For more details, you can [check the documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).

Comment: In my opinion apply here is bad choice.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-not-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code

Comment: Yes, there are many other methods. Like the one given by @BenT below is a very nice solution. I just wanted to show him a general approach to solving the problem.

Comment: ya, depends what need OP, but mainly problem is `apply` are loops, so necessary avoid like here if need performance.

Comment: For your interest @jezrael, I added under my own solution the performance of the different solutions.

Comment: @Mr. Hobo, please see the performance of the different solutions.

Answer (score 3):

you can use `loc` to select the rows and columns to multiply by 10.

```
myDF.loc[myDF['trial'].eq('A'), 'score'] *= 10

print(myDF)
  trial  score
0     A     10
1     B      2
2     A     30
3     B      4
4     A     50
5     B      6
```

and it will be much faster than a looping.
​

Comment: I'm looking for the dup, I have the feeling it exists, but if not it sounds like a common question. was I wrong to use a wiki?

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to do this is using `replace`.

```
myDF = pd.DataFrame({'trial': ['A','B','A','B','A','B'], 'score': [1,2,3,4,5,6]})
myDF['score'] = myDF['score'].mul(myDF['trial'].replace({'A':10, 'B':1}))
```

#### Performance

Below I tested the performance of the different solutions using a dataset of 100000 rows.

```
N=100000
myDF = pd.DataFrame({'trial': np.random.choice(['A', 'B'], N), 'score': np.random.choice(np.arange(0,10), N)})
```

**Given solutions:**

```
%timeit myDF['score'] = myDF['score'].mul(myDF['trial'].replace({'A':10, 'B':1}))
```

22.5 ms ± 109 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

```
%timeit myDF.loc[myDF['trial'].eq('A'), 'score'] *= 10
```

6.4 ms ± 18.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

```
%timeit myDF["score"] = myDF.apply(lambda x : x[1] * 10 if x[0] == "A" else x[1], axis = 1)
```

587 ms ± 2.05 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

```
def updateScore(trial, score):
    return score if trial != 'A' else score * 10

%timeit myDF["score"] = myDF.apply(lambda x : updateScore(trial = x[0], score = x[1]), axis = 1)
```

603 ms ± 4.35 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)